# Debug.WriteLine effecting non debug performance

Tags: c#, .net, loops

Running .exe the presence of the Debug.WriteLine() effects performance 8x.
How can a Debug statement effect performance not in debug?
How can I have a Debug not effect .exe performance?
counterRequals is referenced after so it cannot just skip.
This if is hit over 1 billion times.

```
if (innerInnerLoopCount > 1 && r == innerInnerLoopCount)
{
    counterRequals++;
    Debug.WriteLine("");
}
```

Comment: `Debug` members have the [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) assigned to them so they won't be present in `Release` mode. It sounds like you're running the `Debug` build without the debugger. If you need `Debug` like functionality, consider using the [Trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead although you'll possibly hit perf issues with 1bn hits. Could consider [EventSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource.aspx)

Comment: Just because you're not debugging doesn't mean that you didn't compile in Debug mode.  Did you compile in Debug or Release mode?

Comment: The && operator is expensive if the left operator expression is poorly predictable, the branch prediction fail can make the operation up to about 5 times as slow.   Multiply that by a billion and you have about 2 seconds doing nothing useful.  Swap the operands.  And *do* prefer the fast version that uses no branching at all: `if (r == innerInnerLoopCount & innerInnerLoopCount > 1)`

Comment: @keyboardP The problem was I compiling for Release.  If you will post that as and answer I will accept.  Thanks

Comment: @Paparazzi - I've added my comment as an answer. As a side note, compiling it to release removes all the `Debug` methods from the build so it won't be called at all

Comment: @HansPassant That helped.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Debug` members have the [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) assigned to them so they won't be present in `Release` mode. It sounds like you're running the `Debug` build without the debugger. If you need Debug like functionality, consider using the [Trace class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx) instead although you'll possibly hit perf issues with 1bn hits. If that's the case, you could look at [EventSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource.aspx) which can allow for high performance logging.